# Can I directly cite a picture from Medium?

Tags: citations

I'm writing my thesis and there is one picture from medium I want to use https://shreyusp.medium.com/multi-task-learning-f3ba67eaa836

[image]
It is *Figure 1: Hard and Soft Parameter Sharing*.

Can I directly use the graph by citing its web address? Or is it better to create my own graph?

Comment: You can always say "inspired by %url%", but here is nothing hard that could not be done from scratch in a reasonable time.

Comment: Note that the fact the figure is published in a Medium post rather than an academic paper doesn't really affect the answer, although perhaps the publisher's degree of understanding. Also related: [Is it necessary to obtain permissions for copying figures from published articles in your proposal/dissertation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4787/17254)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off citing it (and the article in which it appears). A cursory search didn't turn up any licensing information, so you have to assume that the image, like the article, is copyrighted by the author(s) or by medium.

I don't know enough about the field, but there is also the issue as to whether this information is "common knowledge" or not. I'm guessing not, which means that without a citation you are open to charges of plagiarism if you recreate it or use it without citation.

If it isn't common knowledge then I suggest that you ask the author for permission to reuse it (with citation) in your thesis. You can then just include the image. I'm pretty sure the author would allow it, if they hold the copyright. It is a bit more complicated if medium has copyright, in which case the author might need to work with them to allow it.

A difficulty with web citation, however, is that web pages disappear. You can include a "date last accessed" in a citation, or you can see if the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org) holds a permanent version.

But, keep in mind that both copyright and plagiarism are issues here and they are not the same thing.

And note that I'm using fairly strict interpretations of the applicable rules, which is certainly appropriate for a thesis.